# finding the minimum weight of a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

i am trying to make a program which calculats the minimum spanning weight using the Kruskal's algorithm,
i have sorted the edges using thier weghts in increasing order and put it in a 2d list .
then i have write a method to get the minimum weight using the sortededge ,
take for sample ,`sortededge = [['1', '2', '1'], ['5', '6', '1'], ['2', '4', '2'], ['3', '6', '2'], ['3', '5', '3'], ['4', '6', '3'], ['3', '4', '5'], ['1', '3', '6']]`
the method is

```
vertexcheck = []
minimumdistance  = 0
def MSW:
    for i in range(len(sortededge)):
        if (sortededge[i][0] not in vertexcheck) or (sortededge[i][1] not in vertexcheck):
            if (sortededge[i][0] not in vertexcheck):
                vertexcheck.append(sortededge[i][0])


            if (sortededge[i][1] not in vertexcheck):
                vertexcheck.append(sortededge[i][1])
            minimumdistance += int(sortededge[i][2])
```

but it doesnot work for all graphs and i would welcome any help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  You can format your code in a readable way by using the "{ }" button in the editor.  Please specify what you mean by "does not work"; what's an example the code fails for?   What is the actual and expected outcome for that example?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm implementation is wrong.

Let an example where your algo fails :

[image]

And the edge will look like this after sorting :

Edges :

```
    1, 2, 1
    3, 4, 2
    2, 3, 5
```

in 1st iteration you will put 1 and 2 in your vertexcheck. updated vertexcheck=[1,2]
in 2nd iteration you will put 3 and 4 in your vertexcheck. updated vertexcheck=[1,2,3,4]
But in 3rd iteration you can't add 2->3 edge because both vertex are present in your vertexcheck.

That's why your implementation giving wrong output :(

Actually, for Kruskal's implementation you need to know and use a data-structure algorithm called Union-Find, which tells you if the current nodes you are trying to connect are already connected :)

If they are already connected then skip the edge because they are already connected by a lower cost :) otherwise connect them ...

As a lot of implementation are available for MST using python, i won't bother giving you one :)

You can find the Pseudocode here :
[Kruskal's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm)

And a sample implementation :
[Kruskal's_implementation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/class/02713-s13/src/mst.py)